# Approximating norms using numerical integration?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces, approximation-theory, norms, numerical-integration

I have a sequence of functions $u_m$ in $H^1(\Omega)$, where $\Omega$ is Lipschitz such that $u_m(x)=\int_{|y|\le \epsilon} \, f_m(x,y) \, dy$, but the integral cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

Q1. Can I use numerical integration to approximate $u_m(x)$ over $\Omega$ say by taking the mid point quadrature formula?

Q2. If $(1)$ holds, i.e $u_m(x) \approx g_m(x)$ over $\Omega$, can I say $||u_m|| \approx ||g_m||$, where $||.||$ denotes the $H^1$ norm?

Comment: What is $g_m$ here?